# How sort() works in this situation?

Tags: javascript

Can you guys explain to me how the sort() works in this situation? The thing I don't understand is by somehow the sort() know how to put everything in order just based on return -1 and 1. One more thing is how the function knows that val1 should point to num property in arr[0] and val2 should point to num property in arr[1]. While the code doesn't have any loop but how it keeps going until having nothing else to loop? Thank you

```
  var arr=[{
  num: 1,
  str: "smallest"
  },{
  num: 2,
  str: "smaller"
    },{
  num: 3,
  str: "biggest"
      }];
  
  arr.sort(function(val1,val2){
    if(val1.num<val2.num){
      return -1;}
    else{
      return 1;}
  });
  console.log(arr);
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: it works correctly ... sorting by the `.num` properties of the objects, in ascending order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `compareFunction`. For example, you can create a new sort method for array:

```js
Array.prototype.bubbleSort = function () {
  const arr = this;
  for (let j = arr.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
    for (let i = 0; i < j; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
        let temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
};
[5,3,2,1,4].bubbleSort(); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Obviously it only works for numbers. By providing a `compareFunction`, it can work for any data:

```js
Array.prototype.bubbleSort = function (compareFunction) {
  const arr = this;
  for (let j = arr.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
    for (let i = 0; i < j; i++) {
      if (compareFunction(arr[i], arr[i + 1]) > 0) {  // <---- changes
        let temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
};
[{name: 'a', age: 4}, {name: 'b', age: 3}].bubbleSort((a, b) => a.age - b.age);
// [{name: 'b', age: 3}, {name: 'a', age: 4}]
```

`compareFunction` is just an override for those operator `< > >= <= ===`.
Its job is just to tell the sort method how to compare two elements.